# Created a synonym, which needs some upvotes

Tags: discussion

We both have marketing-cloud-connect, as well as marketing-cloud-connector as tags in SFSE. I have suggested to [have them as synonyms](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/marketing-cloud-connect/synonyms), or alternatively merging could be considered, as they are so close to each other.

Best regards
Lukas

Comment: i tried to but unfortunately i do not meet the requirements to vote for it.  "2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag".

Comment: I think I can merge them. Which form is preferred in the MC world?

Comment: Thank you @DavidReed The official name is [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged the tag `marketing-cloud-connector` into the tag `marketing-cloud-connect`.